# MSSQL server 2014 express database synchronize to linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

i need to synchronize linked server with primary server in MSSQL server 2014 express.When we do any modification in primary server it should be reflect
on linked server or secondary server . In Express edition Mirroring and Replication are not available. What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Trigger to solve your problem.
First create your trigger actions against a local table created for this test. Create the on insert, update and delete trigger actions which pretty much just execute the same action against the test table.
Once you got this to work, replace the test table by the target linked server table you need to be in sync.

Let me know if that worked for you, than we can talk about the limitation you might face.